# Advice spring mvc http message converter

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to advice spring http message converter but, I can't get it to work.

```
@Pointcut("within(org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter)")
public void converterPointcut() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
public void converterMethodPointcut() {
}

@Around("converterPointcut() && converterMethodPointcut()")
public Object aroundConverter(ProceedingJoinPoint iJoinPoint) {
    Object aProceed = null;
    try {
        aProceed = iJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable anException) {
        anException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aProceed;
}
```

Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) using `within`, you are only advising the Methods of the `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` class, are you sure that's what you want?

b) to weave a library class you need to either [set up](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-load-time-weaver) [load time weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) <s>or run the spring jars through the aspectj compiler (ouch, don't do that)</s>. Do you have load time weaving set up?

c) define can't get it to work: what happens, what doesn't happen?

---

**Update:** I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Don't use AspectJ, just extend the class ([none of the methods are final](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.java?format=ok)) and [register the extended class as `HttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion)

Comment: a) Yes, I want to advice only methods of that class, b) I haven't set up load time weaving, I am using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`, c) The method aroundConverter() is never called.

Comment: @outvir aspectj-autoproxy works for your own code, but you are trying to add advice to existing binary code. you need load time weaving